# use bootstrap without breaking existing website style

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to use Bootstrap to create a small component on my website, however, bootstrap is using some very broad selectors like a{text-decoration: underline;}

this means even if I don't add bootstrap classes to element, bootstrap still changes how it looks.

What I want to do is restricting bootstrap to just that component, but not affect other elements which does not have bootstrap classes. Is this possible?

I know I can override Bootstrap style, but is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: For a small component is the perfect reason to NOT use bootstrap at all. To call in an outside library just for one thing is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing you can do is create a new `bootstrap-theme.css` stylesheet and there replace the styles that are uncomfortable for you with bootstrap.